# dynamic image / captcha image over load-balanced servers

Tags: php, apache, captcha

i have two servers which are load balanced in such a a way that each page request will be served from any one of the servers.

And in the project i am creating captcha images which will be created on any of the server which serves the page, and while loading it in browser ( img src) the call goes to other server because of the load balance implementation.

is there any workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is the best solution.

i fixed the issue by reading up the captcha image as BLOB using [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) function soon after the creating the image, and printed the image as BLOB image over HTML img src tag. so that no http request for image is send to the server.

The problem got solved for me.